when i try to log in using OAuth from google cloud console it only creates a user not an account
i am building an app for my finals and i wanted it to connect with google also, but when i try to register with google, instead of creating both an account and an user it only creates an user and i do not understand why. i mention that i used the signIn method from next-auth/react
this is the url i get after using the button
http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fregister&error=OAuthSignin
<Heading title="Sign up for E~Shop"/>
    <Button outline label="Continue with google"
    icon={AiOutlineGoogle} onClick={()=>{signIn('google')}}/>
    <hr className="bg-slate-300 w-full h-px"></hr>


export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "email",
          type: "text",
        },
        password: {
          label: "password",
          type: "password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
          throw new Error("Invalid username or password");
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });
        if (!user || !user?.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
        }
        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
        }
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages:{
    signIn:'/login'
  },
  debug:process.env.NODE_ENV ===  "development",
  session:{
    strategy:"jwt",
  },
  secret:process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);

Here is the prisma schemas for both user and account

model Account{
    id                  String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    userId              String  @db.ObjectId
    type                String
    provider            String
    providerAccountId   String
    refresh_token       String? @db.String
    acces_token         String? @db.String
    expires_at          Int?
    token_type          String?
    scope               String?
    id_token            String? @db.String
    session_state       String?

    user User @relation(fields: [userId],references: [id],onDelete: Cascade)

    @@unique([provider,providerAccountId])
}

model User{
    id          String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    name        String?
    email       String? @unique
    emailVerified DateTime?
    image       String?
    hashedPassword  String?
    createdAt       DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt       DateTime @updatedAt
    role Role @default(USER)
    accounts    Account[]
}

enum Role{
        USER
        ADMIN
}

and here is how i called
i did this watching a tutorial from 7 months ago, i think that i set the Google_client_id and google Client_secret as they should, but it still only creates an user, never an account
